# react-table useSortBy sets descending on adjacent column not column that is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-table-v7

I am using react-table v7 to create a basic datatable with column sorting. I am adding an `aria-sort` attribute to the column headers (`<th>`) tags.

What I am trying to do is make sure that when someone decides to sort a specific column, when `isSortedDesc` is `true`, the `aria-sort` attribute should get set to `aria-sort='descending'` otherwise it should be set to `aria-sort='ascending'` and if `isSorted` is `true` then set `aria-sort='none'`

I am able to set aria-sort correctly based on the conditions, but the problem I'm running in to is that when I click on `"First Name"` it doesn't change the `aria-sort` attribute for that column but instead changes the `aria-sort` attribute for `"Last Name"` and so on.

Any ideas why this is happening?

You can see the problem in this code sandbox. Inspect the table header and you should see the `aria-sort` attribute on each `<th>`. Try to sort by "First Name" and you will see that the `aria-sort` attribute on "Last Name" changes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sammet-677rfi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why your original behavior happens, but an interesting property emerges that for every *n*-th column that is sorted, the aria attribute on the *n+1*-th column is altered instead. "First Name" toggles "Last Name", "Last Name" toggles "Age", and so on, until the end. Something similar happens if you attempt to add a `sortDirection` attribute to the `column` where you're using sortDirection now. I imagine this is something related to React or JS render/life-cycles, with a simple fix, but I can't think of it right now.